# Declaring remove_action inside a class the same way as add_action

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

When declaring an action in a class, we use this:

```
class the_class{
    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'the_action', array( $this, 'cb_function' ) ); 
    }
    function cb_function(){
        
    }   
}
```

We are trying to declare a remove action in a class, we are trying this:

```
class the_class{
    function __construct(){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array( $this, 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ) ); 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' ), 30 ); 
    }
}
```

But it is not working, what is wrong?

Comment: it depends on which action and callback you're trying to remove and what priority is set on that action and when it's loading originally.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I see, so it is not as straighforward as add_action. This is what we need: `remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );` and `remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );` . We can just add them into a function php file but we would like to include as a part of a plugin for organization. Any help is very appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to write something to remove action, when you're working with a class, should be like this:

**Note: when you use `remove_action` you need to define the priority value as well and some themes can also remove the action and re-apply with different priority so you need to make sure if the theme is changing something, if it is then you need to change your code according to that so that your changes affects the theme changes**

```php
class the_class {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'cb_remove_function' ) );
    }

    public function cb_remove_function() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```